# Random background images every page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know if is possible in my version...
my html code

```
<div id="AvPinkImages" class="AvImages">
    <div id="AvPinkGalleryImages" class="AvGalleryImages">

    <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/768eec43.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>

    <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/a79e6b78.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>  

    <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/27570903.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>     
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js code to get the selected background image

```
function AvBackgroundImages(e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'AvGbtn') {
        var favImage = e.target.style.backgroundImage;
        setCookie('image', favImage);
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = favImage;
        console.log(favImage);
    }
}
document.onclick = AvBackgroundImages;

function AvBackgroundImage() {
    var favImage = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
    var image = getCookie('image');
    if (image === '') {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = favImage;
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = image;
    }
}
window.onload = function(){
AvBackgroundImage();
};
```

What I want to do achieve is a switch button (**on**/**off**). If is **on** change backgroud image every page load, if is **off** show the selected image on background?

Comment: I'm still a little unsure about what you are exactly trying to achieve. Did you want a button that would change the background images?

Comment: No I want a code to change the backruond image every page load, that code what I have just show. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    // default image
    img{
        background:  url('off.jpg');
    }
    // on image if IMG has a class on in it
    img.on{
        background:  url('on.jpg');
    }
</style>

<script>
      // based on your value in session storage or local storage
      document.querySelector('img').addClass('on');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that what I want to do is to get images form this id `AvPinkGalleryImages` and show in Random in background every page load. thanks again

Comment: in the above code instead of document.querySelector('img').addClass('on'); do document.querySelector('#AvPinkGalleryImages').addClass('on'); And in css style instead of img put #AvPinkGalleryImages